# Mail not sending in mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, email

i have posted my source that having porblem named

**A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 68.178.232.62:25**

i have implemented by ref of

http://developmentfaction.blogspot.in/2013/03/sending-email-with-javascript-and-aspnet.html

please help me to solve this issue

thanks in advance :)

View Page

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Emailto", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Position, new { @readonly = "readonly", @id = "Position", @name = "Position" })
  <input type="text" value="" id="txtname" name="txtname" required />
  <input type="email" value="" id="txtemail" name="fromEmail"  required />
<input type="submit" id="btnApply" name="btnApply" value="Apply" />
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]
        public ActionResult Emailto(string Position, string txtname, string fromEmail)

        {
            EmailManager.SendMessage(Position, txtname, fromEmail);
            return Redirect("Index");
        }
```

EmailManager

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public static void SendMessage(string Position, string txtname, string fromEmail)
        {
            const string SERVER = "relay-hosting.secureserver.net";
            const string TOEMAIL = "acb@gmail.com";
            MailAddress from = new MailAddress(fromEmail);
            MailAddress to = new MailAddress(TOEMAIL);
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);

            message.Subject = "Position " + Position;
            message.Body = "Message from: " + Position + " at " +
                           fromEmail + "\n\n" + txtname;
            message.IsBodyHtml = false;
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(SERVER);
            client.Send(message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: *connected host has failed to respond 68.178.232.62:25* the error is obvious, as the network connection cannot be established. Is the port open?

Comment: sorry am new to mvc.. can you please tell me how to check port is open or not .. @Raptor

Comment: It's **not** related to codes. Please use `telnet` to diagnose network connection. Search Google.

Comment: Have you configured the credentials and port of `SmtpClient`.

Comment: nope , is required to configure  credentials for SmtpClient !!  @MahbuburRahman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to be supplying a password or port for the smtp.

```
var loginInfo = new NetworkCredential(email, password);
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(SERVER, 587);


                client.EnableSsl = true;
                client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                client.Credentials = loginInfo;
                client.Send(mail);
```

Hope this helps